# How to align two images to be on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two images on top of each other and then fade between them on hover...however I can't align them correctly. How do I best do this? It's difficult because I have centered  the first image and it's within a cell......
I'm trying to align the ones in box1

```
.logo1 {
background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/pisojjj/image/upload/v1481695899/ACE-white_pcfefd.png");
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
}
    .logo1bg {
        background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/pisojjj/image/upload/v1481695899/Ace-colour_qjb911.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absoulte;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Codepen will help a lot with this.
http://codepen.io/pisoj1/pen/dOgjmJ

Also I have a request if someone knows how to do it quickly when looking at the pen...when it goes responsive, box1 is presently the top middle box that gets placed on top of the stack...I want box5 to do that now instead of box1, any suggestions on how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the second div and put the change the  background image of `.logo1` on hover

```
.box1:hover .logo1 {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/pisojjj/image/upload/v1481695899/Ace-colour_qjb911.png");
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoaKLe

Comment: Thanks! That works pretty well and cuts out a lot of extra code.

Comment: Have done, just doesn't show publicly until I have +15

Answer (score 0):

Why you added `background-size: contain;`?

I have modified it, check Codepen

```
.logo1, .logo2, .logo3, .logo4, .logo5, .logo6, .logo7, .logo8, .logo9 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoeBve?editors=1100

Comment: Originally I was planning to have a different image in there. Not related to the logo so that was why